# After Cleaning a Maven Project from command prompt the server runtime library gets deleted

Tags: maven, eclipse-kepler

I am new to maven.

1. I created a dynamic web project and converted to maven project.
2. Then from command prompt i cleaned the project using `mvn eclipse:clean`
3. I refreshed the project in eclipse
4. It comes up with an error like JSP Problem : (the server runtime library deleted)

> The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the
>   Java Build Path      home.jsp

After adding the server runtime library manually the problem solved.
**Is there any other way to solve the problem** or **the problem will not occur at all.**

Comment: did you performed mvn eclipse:install after clean?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project

Comment: @Bala am looking for a solution in maven not in ant or manually..

Comment: @Downvoters please let me if any problem with question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below dependency in your *pom.xml* to avoid the exception:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```